# Set Spring SolrDocument Collection name based on PropertyValue

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I want to set values Spring SolrDocument Collection based on application.yml value.

```
@Data
@SolrDocument(collection = @Value("${solr.core}"))
public class SearchableProduct {
}
```

Comment: we can take property values and use in any function.@SolrDocument(collection = expects string no matter from where you bring it.

Answer (score 0):

Hoi Michela,

Ok, I had the same Problem and I found a solution: SpEL

it is described in details here:[Spring Data for Apache Solr](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/4.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference)

1. you have to add the EL-expression to the Annotation

   ```
   @SolrDocument(collection = "#{@serverSolrContext.getCollectionName()}")
   public class SOLREntity implements Serializable {
        .....
   }
   ```
2. you have to provide a the *serverSolrContext* Bean with the method *getCollectionName()*.

   ```
   @Value("${solr.core}")
   private String core;

   public String getCollectionName() {
       return core;
   }
   ```
3. you have to write in our application.properties the following core entry.

   ```
   solr.core=myOwnCoreName
   ```

   That's it actually, BUT
4. if you get the following Exception, so as I did:

**org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean**

You have to have the following in your Configuration Bean

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = { "de.solr.db" })
    @Profile("default")
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class ServerSolrContext extends AbstractSolrConfiguration {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerSolrContext.class);

        @Resource
        private Environment environment;

        @Value("${solr.core}")
        private String core;

        public String getCollectionName() {
            return core;
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            System.out.println(core);
        }

        @Bean
        public SolrClient solrClient() {
            String url = environment.getProperty("solr.server.url");
            String user = environment.getProperty("solr.server.user");
            String password = environment.getProperty("solr.server.password");

            CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));
            SSLContext sslContext = null;
            try {
                sslContext = ReportConfiguration.getTrustAllContext();
            }
            catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            LayeredConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
                            .addInterceptorFirst(new PreemptiveAuthInterceptor()).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                            .build();

            SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder().withHttpClient(httpClient).withBaseSolrUrl(url).build();
            return client;
        }

        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "solrTemplate")
        public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(@Qualifier("mySolrTemplate") SolrTemplate solrTemplate) {
            return solrTemplate;
        }


        @Bean("mySolrTemplate")
        public SolrTemplate mySolrTemplate(SolrClient solrClient, SolrConverter solrConverter) {
            return new SolrTemplate(new HttpSolrClientFactory(solrClient), solrConverter); 

        }

        @Override
        public SolrClientFactory solrClientFactory() {
            return new HttpSolrClientFactory(solrClient());
        }

    }
```

The last 3 Methods are doing the Trick, that cost me a while to find the right solution:

it is here, so actually I was lucky to find this:

[Allow PropertyPlaceholders in @SolrDocument solrCoreName](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-304?focusedCommentId=161669&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel)